# How can I format axis labels with exponents with ggplot2 and scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2

With the new version ggplot2 and scales, I can't figure out how to get axis label in scientific notation. For example:

```
x <- 1:4
y <- c(0, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003)

dd <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

gives me

[image: Example ggplot with scales]

I'd like the axis labels to be 0, 5 x 10^-5, 1 x 10^-4, 1.5 x 10^-4, etc. I can't figure out the correct combination of `scale_y_continuous()` and `math_format()` (at least I think those are what I need).

`scale_y_log10()` log transforms the axis, which I don't want. `scale_y_continuous(label = math_format())` just gives me 10^0, 10^5e-5, etc. I see why the latter gives that result, but it's not what I'm looking for.

I am using ggplot2_0.9.1 and scales_0.2.1

Comment: I'm confused; those values (0, 5^-5, 1^-4, 1.5^-4) don't really match up with the data ranges in your plot.

Comment: Correct -- that wasn't clear. I've edited now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651903/ggplot2-y-axis-ticks-not-showing-up-on-a-log-scale ?

Comment: @BenBolker I don't think that this is really a duplicate of the one you link to, in that that question was about a logarithmic scale and labels formatted as a base to a power (such that the powers are then linearly increasing). This is about labels on a linear scale in scientific notation.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I adapted Brian's answer and I think I got what you're after.

Simply by adding a parse() to the scientific_10() function (and changing 'x' to the correct 'times' symbol), you end up with this:

```
x <- 1:4
y <- c(0, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003)

dd <- data.frame(x, y)

scientific_10 <- function(x) {
  parse(text=gsub("e", " %*% 10^", scales::scientific_format()(x)))
}

ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()+scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_10)
```

[image]

You might still want to smarten up the function so it deals with 0 a little more elegantly, but I think that's it!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This solution works but it prints out a number like 1e+03 as 10^+03. Is there a way to have it print out as 10^3 instead?

Comment: @BerkU. Yes.  Use `scientific_10 <- function(x) {
  parse(text=gsub("e\\+*", " %*% 10^", scales::scientific_format()(x)))
}` to ignore the "+"  symbol.

Comment: The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18526649/2295964) looks more canonical than this accepted one!

Comment: @YanFoto No it's not. The answer below is in log10 format, the question is not supposed that.

Answer (score 37):

As per the comments on the accepted solution, OP is looking to format exponents as exponents. This can be done with the `trans_format` and `trans_breaks` functions in the *scales* package:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)

    x <- 1:4
    y <- c(0, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003)
    dd <- data.frame(x, y)

    ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
    scale_y_log10("y",
        breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
        labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried it but I got the plot upside down. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639120/ggplot2-transform-y-axis-in-bar-plot-using-scale-y-log10. I will appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: @aelwan: I'll answer in the other thread, but a logarithmic scale does not really work with a barplot because there can be no zero mark. I would consider just use geom_errorbar() and not geom_bar() .

Answer (score 14):

```
scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_format())
```

gives labels with e instead of 10:

[image]

I suppose if you really want 10's in there, you could then wrap that in another function.

```
scientific_10 <- function(x) {
  gsub("e", " x 10^", scientific_format()(x))
}

ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_10)
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way to combine this with the strategy in `math_format()` to get the exponents formatted properly, but it was getting complicated.

Comment: Is it possible to get the exponents as actual exponents? Otherwise, this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Kevin It might be. The general approach would be to make the labels plotmath expressions. I don't know if you can return expressions for a labels function or not. I tried a few things, but couldn't get anything to work easily. Hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: @joran I've added a solution to show how to format the exponents as you wanted (I know this is quite old, however).

Answer (score 12):

Riffing off of Tom's answer above, the following removes + signs, and handles 0 better:

```
scientific_10 = function(x) {
  ifelse(
    x==0, "0",
    parse(text = sub("e[+]?", " %*% 10^", scientific_format()(x)))
  )
} 

## used as
scale_y_continuous(label = scientific_10)
```

Comment: nice! Too bad this kind of option is not in ggplot directly.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm editing to use a single `gsub` instead of two - we can combine the patterns to clean things up.

Comment: I'm editing to use a single `gsub` instead of two - we can combine the patterns to clean things up. And because there will be at most one `"e"` we can use `sub` instead of `gsub` for the tiniest bit of efficiency.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a version of scientific_10 that avoids the scales package; it also removes leading zeroes in exponents (10^04 to 10^4, etc.). This was adapted from the helpful answers given above.

I've also included wrapper scale functions below.

```
scientific_10 <- function(x) {
    xout <- gsub("1e", "10^{", format(x),fixed=TRUE)
    xout <- gsub("{-0", "{-", xout,fixed=TRUE)
    xout <- gsub("{+", "{", xout,fixed=TRUE)
    xout <- gsub("{0", "{", xout,fixed=TRUE)
    xout <- paste(xout,"}",sep="")
    return(parse(text=xout))
}

scale_x_log10nice <- function(name=NULL,omag=seq(-10,20),...) {
    breaks10 <- 10^omag
    scale_x_log10(name,breaks=breaks10,labels=scientific_10(breaks10),...)
}

scale_y_log10nice <- function(name=NULL,omag=seq(-10,20),...) {
    breaks10 <- 10^omag
    scale_y_log10(name,breaks=breaks10,labels=scientific_10(breaks10),...)
}

scale_loglog <- function(...) {
    list(scale_x_log10nice(...),scale_y_log10nice(...))
}

qplot(x=exp(5*rnorm(100)),geom="density",kernel="rectangular") + 
    scale_x_log10nice()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this became really easy using the great `ggtext`-package.
What I did was:

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = log10(mpg), y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x){return(paste0("10^", x))}) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_markdown()
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Merging the previous answer I've created a function that can get arbitrary power ot tens for x and y as a multiply factor and then create the plot adding the factor near the axes

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(1,25)
y <- rnorm(25)/10000
dd <- data.frame(x, y)

trim10 <- function(x) {
  parse(text=gsub(".*e", "x10^", scales::scientific_format()(x)))
}


ggplot_trim10 <- function(x,y,xfac,yfac,...){
        
    xnew    <- x*xfac 
    ynew    <- y*yfac 
    
    dd      <- data.frame(xnew,ynew)
    
    xunit   <- abs(max(xnew) - min(xnew))
    yunit   <- abs(max(ynew) - min(ynew))
    
    x_min_label <- min(xnew) - xunit*0.1
    x_max_label <- max(xnew) - xunit*0.1
    y_min_label <- min(ynew) - yunit*0.1
    y_max_label <- max(ynew) - yunit*0.1
    
    ggplot(data=dd, aes(x=xnew, y=ynew),...) +
    geom_line() +
    annotate("text", x = x_max_label, y = y_min_label, label = trim10(xfac)) +
    annotate("text", x = x_min_label, y = y_max_label, label = trim10(yfac)) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(xnew), max(xnew)),ylim = c(min(ynew),max(ynew)), clip = "off")
    }

ggplot_trim10(x,y,10,10)
```

as a note I know that "x" is not the correct symbol but I was getting a bit crazy mixing `expression`, `paste` etc. if anyone will fix it it would be great