# Plotting values like 1.10e15, 1.3e15, 2e15 using ggplot or spplot

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, plot

i am tring to plot data, which range between 1e15-2e15, unfortunately i am not able to plot a nice line graph.How to make y-axis to be abbreviated into 1e15 instead of 1000000000000000in graph   [DATA Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QVHrhsZAzz67mlJDNBJHTI4trtSCBUPq)

```
>library(readxl)
>library("xlsx")
>library(ggplot2)
>test <- read.xlsx2("/filepath/test.xlsx", 1, header=TRUE)  
>ggplot(test,aes(x=NO2, y=  SA)) + geom_point()
>class(test$SA)
[1] "factor"
> dput(test)
structure(list(NO2 = structure(1:11, .Label = c("2008", "2009", 
"2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018"), class = "factor"), Bangladesh = structure(c(1L, 4L, 
3L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("1927189454271550", 

> scientific <- function(x) {
    parse(text=gsub("e", " %*% 10^", scales::scientific_format()(x)))
  }
> ggplot(test,aes(x=NO2, y=  SA)) + geom_point() +scale_y_continuous(label=scientific)
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
> ggplot(test,aes(x=NO2, y=  SA)) + geom_point() +scale_y_continuous(label=scales::scientific_format())
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

[image]

```
>ggplot(test,aes(x=NO2, y= as.numeric(SA)))+scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_10)
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure the y-axis variable has not been coded as a factor? What dose `class(test$SA)` give?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762287/how-can-i-format-axis-labels-with-exponents-with-ggplot2-and-scales

Comment: It would be helpful if you `dput(test)`.

Comment: I dnt get it..if it is a factor? ```dput()``` gives a long list..i have just took a part of the output

Comment: use `scale_y_continuous(label=scales::scientific_format())`

Comment: ```scale_y_continuous(label=scales::scientific_format())```Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: Your `SA` variable should be numeric so you should try first `ggplot(test,aes(x=NO2, y=  as.numeric(SA)))`, but without sample data that is kind of a shot in the dark.

Comment: Uploaded the data

Comment: You didn't uploaded the data, you just provided a screenshot of the excel file, which doesn't let us see how it is imported to R.

Comment: It is an excel file in google drive..You have to download it

Comment: @DavidJorquera yes it was needed to be numeric..Thanks all.. managed to plot

Answer (score 1):

```
> test$SA=as.numeric(levels(test$SA))[test$SA]
> ggplot(test,aes(x=NO2, y=  SA)) + geom_point() +scale_y_continuous(label=scales::scientific_format())
```

[image]