# ggplot2 - dealing with large counts in histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, histogram

I've plotted a histogram of raster values using ggplot2 following this tutorial (https://datacarpentry.org/r-raster-vector-geospatial/01-raster-structure/index.html).

My raster image has a very large number of pixels (millions). As a result, the Y label (Number of Pixels) has numbers that go up to the power of 6 (e.g., 0e+00, 3e+06, 6e+06, 9e+06).

For scientific reporting/journal publishing, I imagine it would be better to have more meaningful labels on the Y axis. Is there any advice on how to deal with reporting large counts (millions) in ggplot2 histograms so it is more meaningful?

I'm afraid I can't share the plot to the sensitive nature of the data.

Example code:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_histogram(data = raster_converted_to_df, aes(raster_value))
```

Comment: E.g. `ggplot(diamonds, aes(x)) + geom_histogram() + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(scale = 1/1000, suffix = 'k'))`

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762287/how-can-i-format-axis-labels-with-exponents-with-ggplot2-and-scales) can help.