# R solution for scientific notation formatting

Tags: r, scientific-notation

I am looking for a solution to format numbers in R under scientific notation, using the standard format *a* × 10 <sup>b</sup>. This is required in several peer-reviewed scientific journals, and modifying graphs by hand may become tedious.

Below, an example of how the R standard "E notation" looks like, and how I would like it to look like:

```
var<-0.00000000000000000000000000000031267781238
plot(1,main=var)
```

[image: R scientific notation]

Thanks for any suggestion you will have!

Comment: From a typographic point of view, there should be a "×" (times symbol), not "x".

Comment: Corrected in the text, thanks! (I couldn't change it in the example image, sorry).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution exists in the function ***scinot***, from the recent version of the R package [corto](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corto/index.html), available on CRAN. The function generates an expression out of a single value (or a vector of values), which can then be printed with the correct superscript.

Usage:

```
library(corto)    
scinot(0.00000543) # expression("5.43" ~ x ~ 10^"-6")
```

A "graphical" demonstration, taken from the function examples:

```
numbers<-c(3.456e-12,0.00901,5670000,-3.16e18,0.000004522,rnorm(5,sd=0.0000001))
plot(0,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10),type="n")
text(c(2,6),c(10,10),labels=c("Before","After"),font=2)
for(i in 10:1){
    text(c(2,6),c(i-1,i-1),labels=c(numbers[i],scinot(numbers)[i]))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This does even more than I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function (with times and minus symbols), inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18530540/13460602). You can use `"~ x ~ 10^"` if you want an `x`.

```r
scientific_10 <- function(x, ...) {
  parse(text = gsub("e", "%*%10^", scales::label_scientific(...)(x)))
}

plot(1, main = scientific_10(var, digits = 5))
```

[image]

Comment: I liked your previous version (with the times symbol) better. I know @Thrawn has an "x" in their example but typographically it is not correct. Your solution is also better in that it prints minus signs as minus signs, not as dashes.