# how to add a plot to log plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I ploting in log scale

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(tibble)
tibble(
x = seq(1, 10, .01),
y = sin(log(x)*pi) + 2
) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
geom_line() + 
scale_x_continuous(trans = log_trans()) + 
scale_y_continuous(trans = log_trans())
```

how can I add to this plot the data from

```
    tibble(
   x1 = seq(2, 11, .01),
   y1 = sin(log(x1)*pi) + 2
   )
```

Comment: typo, need to change `log(x)` to `log(x1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

- you need to *un*-`log` transform the `y1` data, since ggplot assumes all data needs to be transformed; and
- you need to map the new variable names

Starting with your original plot unchanged (but assigned to `gg`):

```r
gg <- tibble(
    x = seq(1, 10, .01),
    y = sin(log(x)*pi) + 2
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = log_trans()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = log_trans())

# fixing log(x) -> log(x1)
newdata <- tibble(
  x1 = seq(2, 11, .01),
  y1 = sin(log(x1)*pi) + 2
)
```

We can plot with:

```r
gg + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x1),
            data = mutate(newdata, y = exp(y1)), color = "red")
```

[image: ggplot log axes with added data]

FYI, unless you need `scale_*_continuous` for other reasons, I think `scale_*_log10()` presents better looking default ticks.

```r
gg <- tibble(
    x = seq(1, 10, .01),
    y = sin(log(x)*pi) + 2
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_log10()
gg + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x1), data = mutate(newdata, y = exp(y1)), color = "red")
```

[image: same image using scale_x_log10]

---

Another alternative (not sure what you're going for) is more generic and completely ancillary to the log-axis issue: we assign `data=`, but because the original aesthetics `x` and `y` are not both present, we need to map them explicitly.

```r
gg +
  geom_line(aes(x = x1, y = y1), data = newdata, color = "red")
```

[image: another ggplot, this time the red line overlaps]

Comment: thanks, but i think there is a problem in y scale, when we plot newdata  alone, they are between 1 and 3. but when plotting it with gg they are now from 3 to above 10. any explainations?

Comment: you tell me ... what _exactly_ do you expect this to look like? You have non-log data that you plot in a lot scale, and then you have log-data ... do you expect it to be double-logged?

Comment: see my edit @Tpellirn, perhaps that's it?

Comment: in fact i am trying to plot like loglog  in matlab

Comment: That doesn't clear it up for me. I look at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html and I see two scales, both in "log", with appropriate major/minor gridlines and a curve. That's what I think I'm giving you here. Please explain in words what is wrong with the curves we see here.

Comment: thanks the curvs are correct. just aside, do you know how we show on the y axis 10^0   10^1  10^2   like the plots in matlab? mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html

Comment: would be great if you have an idea

Comment: See https://www.statology.org/ggplot2-log-scale/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/10762287/3358272 for different methods of adjusting the axis labels on a log10 scale. Note that your data does not benefit from 10^1 or higher, I'm assuming your real data has a broader range. Hope this helps!