# Formating numerical tick labels into exponential notation if over certant value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im aiming to make quite a complex plot with faceting and differnt scailes of data due to the large numbers i need to use scientific notation but as i aim to publish my final work it actuly needs to be exponential notation i.e. 5.0x10^05 = 500,000. i have already found the code to do this on a simple individual graph [How can I format axis labels with exponents with ggplot2 and scales?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762287/how-can-i-format-axis-labels-with-exponents-with-ggplot2-and-scales).

```
    label_exponential <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x==0, "0", parse(text=gsub("[+]", "", gsub("e", " %*% 10^", scales::scientific_format()(x)))))
  }
```

[image]

but i have multiple catagorical variables that i need to facet.
so i would like my facets with max data <10,000 to use standerd numeric labels.
i have partly sucseeded with a ifelse below but it reformats individule datapoints not the whole axies. as you can see in the 2nd graph. (just for clarification I'm aiming for Cu, and Fe plots to show ..x10^.. and Ca to show normal numeric.

```
label_exponential_v2<-function(x) {
  ifelse(x > 10000,
    ifelse(x == 0,"0",parse(text = gsub("[+]","",gsub("e"," %*% 10^",scales::scientific_format()(x))))),
    format(x)
  )
}
```

[image]

my thoughts to solve this were to add `max()` but this prodices a error i am unsure how to fix. Error in `get_labels()`:
! `breaks` and `labels` are different lengths

I would appreciate any advice anyone has. my real data is quite big so manually doing this isn't viable.

```
label_exponential_v3<-function(x) {
  ifelse(max(x) > 10000,
         ifelse(x == 0,"0",parse(text = gsub("[+]","",gsub("e"," %*% 10^",scales::scientific_format()(x))))),
         format(x)
  )
}
```

test data and plot

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  x = seq(1, 10000, by = 500),
  Fe = x + 25,
  Ca = (x + 25) * 0.25,
  Cu = (x + 25) * 2
)%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = !x)

ggplot(df, aes(x, value)) + 
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(vars(name),scales = "free")+
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = label_exponential_v3
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the `ggh4x` package which via `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` allows to individually set the positional scales per panel.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggh4x)

label_exponential_v4 <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x == 0,
    "0",
    parse(text = gsub("[+]", "", gsub("e", " %*% 10^", scales::scientific_format()(x))))
  )
}

scales_y <- df |>
  split(~name) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    if (max(x$value) > 10000) {
      scale_y_continuous(
        labels = label_exponential_v4
      )
    }
  })

ggplot(df, aes(x, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(name), scales = "free") +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(y = scales_y)
```

[image]